# vc++ unresolved external symbol (cannot call constructor)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker-errors

I have a VC++ solution with two projects. Project B references project A. Project B also has as Include Directory (Properties/Configuration Properties/C++/Additional Include Directories) the folder from Project A. No namespaces are used.

When i Import the header from a Project A class like `#include "someFolder\SomeClass.h"` then I'm able to declare a pointer to the class.

```
SomeClass *sc;
```

But as soon as i call the constructor it won't compile. IntelliSense doesn't show any errors.

```
SomeClass *sc = new SomeClass("someString");
```

I get:

> error LNK2001: "unresolved external symbol "public_ thiscall SomeClass::SomeClass(..." and "error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals".

The constructor is public just like the methods from SomeClass. The funny thing is that I can compile when calling methods from SomeClass in Project B. Only the cunstructor does not seem to work.

Comment: This is clearly a *linker error*, not a compiler error. So things like accessibility are not the problem. Are you piecing all your translation units together correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to link the object code compiled from "SomeClass.cpp". If Project A compiles to a static library, then add a reference to it.

Comment: I can decide myself to what Project A compiles because I have the sources (I used .exe in the described problem). What would be the easiest way to link the object code please? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I think the best option is to compile Project A as static library (*.lib), and put its path into Linker/Input/Additional dependencies. You could use the cpp itself, the object file, or a dll or exe too, but lib is the usual way.

Comment: Ok, A.lib is now in the Debug folder from the solution. The value of "Additional Dependencies" is now "A.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)". Unfortunately now i get the linker error: "error LNK1104: cannot open file A.lib'"

Comment: You have to add the path too, not just the filename.

Comment: Great, now it works thanks. I used "Debug/A.lib". Instead of adding the path here it is also possible to add the full path until Debug into "Linker/General/Additional Library Directories"

Answer (score 1):

The source does compile, this is a linker error. You need to add the library (.lib) files from Project A to the linker command in Project B.